# Remove all strings that have duplicates

Tags: notepad++

I am not trying to remove just the duplicate strings. which would result in leaving ONE instance of the string in question after all duplicates are removed. Instead, should a duplicate be found, remove all instances, including the original, so that string would no longer exist at all. For example, with a source file of

```
Huey
Huey
Louie
Huey
Dewey
Donald
Uncle Scrooge 
Donald
Daffy
```

such a script would result in

```
Louie 
Dewey 
Uncle Scrooge  
Daffy
```

Note that this example doesn't represent what the data looks like, it is just a clarification of the logic I want to apply to duplicated text.  I'm using Notepad++.

Comment: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/15297/scripts-creating-editing/2 may be helpful.

Comment: May you sort the file? If yes it will be easy to do. Otherwise, you can't do that within Notepad++. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Sorting in Notepad++, BTW, would require the plugin Linesort http://www.scout-soft.com/linesort/ or equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL Plugin for your scenario.
In order to install it, first you need to have PluginManager installed. Visit this link: https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases. Choose the version that suits your N++ and download it.

When unpacked it has the following structure.

PluginManager_v1.4.11_x64
    |---plugins
        |---PluginManager.dll
    |---updater
        |---gpup.exe

For the purpose of this post I've downloaded the zip 64-bit version of N++. When unpacked it already contains plugins and updater folders. I simply copied the files from PluginManager to N++ folders.
Let's start N++
[image]

Let's install SQL plugin.
[image]

Next step is to put the data into N++. SQL plugin requires a column name. Any name can be chosen. I simply picked 'MyColumn'. It also requires a delimiter for a column. I used Regex for it. In replace window (Ctrl+H):
Find what: \r\n|$ 
Replace with: ,\r\n

Now we have a column name and delimiters in every line.
[image]

Let's finally run the SQL plugin.
SQL statement: Select MyColumn from Data GROUP BY MyColumn HAVING COUNT(MyColumn) = 1
Delimiter: ,
[image]

In the output we get the expected results.
[image]

Comment: What if you are missing SQL plugin from the list?

Comment: The solution to my last comment is installing the 32bit version of Notepad++. The SQL plugin is not available in the 64bit version